# Getting values and summing up them from the second table using other keys

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sum

First table

```
ID  Desc    Effective date  Alias
1   abc 12-JAN-10   A1
2   efg 10-FEB-11   A2
3   hij 03-MAR-11   A3
4   klm 05-APR-12   A4
```

Second table

```
Split Date  Alias   Value
13-JAN-10   A1  2
14-JAN-11   A1  3
09-FEB-11   A2  5
04-MAR-12   A3  7
25-DEC-12   A3  1
21-JUL-13   A4  2
30-NOV-12   A4  3
```

Resulting table:

```
ID  Desc    Effective date  Alias   Value
1   abc 12-JAN-10   A1  5   --it got 5 because it sums up values from 2nd table where effective date >split date
2   efg 10-FEB-11   A2  1
3   hij 03-MAR-11   A3  8
4   klm 05-APR-12   A4  5
```

Condition:

Sum all the values from the second table where Effective_date > Split Date using Effective date and Alias from the first table as keys to the second table.
If it did not find effective_date > split date, then value in the resulting table should be 1.

Comment: What have you done so far? Show your code unless you want somebody else to pull your chestnuts out of the fire.

Comment: Im only able to create query to create table 1. Table 1 is from 2 different tables which i joined. Now, I'm stuck on joining this 'second table'

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the following query ?

```
select t1.id, t1.desc, t1.effective_date, t1.alias, nvl(sum(t2.value), 1) value
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t2.alias (+) = t1.alias
  and t2.split_date (+) > t1.effective_date
group by t1.id, t1.desc, t1.effective_date, t1.alias
```

The joins used are old-styled, but I think this can work.

Comment: I tried your logic but it seems it does not add the values that satisfy the condition. The condition to add values is that it should find all rows in table 2 which t2.alias = t2.alias and t2.split_date>t1.effective_date. If it does not find any dates, then default value should be 1.

Comment: Alright then, I changed the inequality, is it ok now ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method using `left outer join`:

```
select t1.id, t1.desc, t1.effective_date, t1.alias,
       coalesce(sum(t2.value), 1) as value
from table1 t1 left outer join
     table2 t2
     on t1.alias = t2.alias and
        t1.effective_date < t2.split_date
group by t1.id, t1.desc, t1.effective_date, t1.alias;
```

I changed the logic to `t1.effective_date < t2.split_date` to match the results in the question, although this is the opposite logic that you describe.

Comment: your logic adds all the values when it did not find effective_date > split_date. When it find though, it defaulted value to 1

Comment: I'd like to clarify with this example: Effective Date = 20-DEC-10, Split Dates included these dates: 19-DEC-10, 21-DEC-10, 30-DEC-10. It should add all values from 21-DEC-10 and 31-DEC-10, it should not include the value in 19-DEC-10. Another example is, if Effective Date = 20-DEC-10, and Split Dates = 18-DEC-10 and 19-DEC-10, the value should be defaulted to 1, no need to sum up.

Comment: @user3279639 . . . That is what this query should be doing, assuming that the dates are actually stored as dates.  If it is not working, perhaps you are storing the dates as strings.